# Translating non-existent keys with ng-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

By default, if I try to translate a non-existent key using the `$translate` service or the `translate` filter, the key itself is returned.

e.g. `$translate.instant('no.such.key') === 'no.such.key'`

Is there a way to change this (per-invocation, rather than globally) so that `null` is returned instead?

Alternatively, does `ng-translate` provide a more concise way than this to show a translation only if it exists?

```
<div ng-if="('no.such.key' | translate) !== 'no.such.key')">
    {{'no.such.key' | translate}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom error handler where you can control the text that is displayed when the key cannot be found.

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/17_custom-error-handler

I copy and paste below the example from this page.

```
app.factory('customTranslationHandler', function () {
  return function (translationID, uses) {
    // return the following text as a translation 'result' - this will be
    // displayed instead of the language key.
    return 'NO DEFAULT KEY';
  };
});
```

Maybe preferable for you would be to instead silently log missing keys. See https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/16_error-handling

Answer (score 0):

Best way to change this per invocation basis is to create a custom filter and translate inside of it.

$filter enables use of all filters within code so we can test the translate return and instead return null. This behavior doesn't override the default translate filter so you can use only where needed.

```js
angular
  .module('app')
  .filter('translateNull', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(value) {
      //Store translation to test and return
      const tempValue = $filter("translate")(value);
      //If translate returns the same key sent we return null
      if (tempValue === value) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return tempValue;
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11